# iOS: CGPDFDocumentGetMediaBox unavailable

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created a simple view based application using Xcode and I tried using CGPDFDocumentGetMediaBox method as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
CGPDFDocumentRef r;
CGRect cg = CGPDFDocumentGetMediaBox(r, 0);
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

However, I get a compile error saying that the method is unavailable:

> /Users/s/Documents/test/Classes/testAppDelegate.m:27:0 /Users/s/Documents/test/Classes/testAppDelegate.m:27: error: 'CGPDFDocumentGetMediaBox' is unavailable (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFDocument.h:117)

I can see from the Apple documents- Deprecated in Mac OS X version 10.3 and later.
But doesn't deprecated mean that the methods should no be used but are still available? I can see the declaration in the header file: CGPDFDocument.h

Mac version: 10.6.8
Xcode version: 3.2.6
iOS SDK: 4.3

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If it's deprecated there is a reason...Did you try to use the alternative function CGPDFPageGetBoxRect?

Comment: Does that mean that if a method is deprecated it is "unavailable" and throws compile errors? My understanding of 'deprecated' was that the method should not be used, but it is still available. Is my understanding wrong here?

Comment: No no, it's correct (at least it should). What I mean is that, once a function is deprecated, you are not supposed to use it anymore, and Apple is free to remove it. Actually the method still appears in the doc, so I suppose it's still available (otherwise Apple should have removed it...but Apple is made of humans). I don't know the reason of your error, but maybe things automatically fix if you simply use the recommended function (which is also a good habit).

Comment: It's deprecated only on Mac OS X. On iOS, it was never available.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)` instead. Note that it takes a `CGPDFPageRef` instead of a `CGPDFDocumentRef`. This is because different pages may have different media boxes. If you're sure your document's pages are all the same size and have the same layout, you can just use the document's first page (via `CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1)`.)